# Get 404 error while retrieving metadata only using dotnet-svcutil

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

Well, the problem is very strange, I have a WCF service served on a production environment with .Net framework 4.5.2, it's working well on the related WPF client.

And now, I'm coding on a test project using .Net 5, and this WCF server is running on localhost for convenience, the WPF client on it is also on local, the URL of WCF service is like http://localhos:port/Services/XXXXX.svc and on https, works fine in the WPF client, and of course, can both access normally on browser, and using Visual Studio Connected Services I can retrieve the services from both URL as well. But the strange thing is, if I use dotnet-svcutil to retrieve the service, it returns Http error 404 and can't generate client code, but if use svcutil from dotnet framework 4.8, it retrieves metadata and generate the code perfectly.

Comment: Would you share some code please?

Comment: Not so convenience, but the code works well on production and localhost with its WPF client, and works fine while using svcutil from dotnet framework and Visual Studio Connected Service. Just get Http error 404 while using dotnet-svcutil.

Comment: Try to use the URL with singleWsdl at the end

Comment: According to your description, it may be a feature issue of Framework 4.8 and 4.5.2, and the bug was fixed in 4.8.

Comment: Yes, have tried wsdl and singlewsdl, 404 as well, maybe this is a bug as the comment said. I'm very sorry about no code here, because the code is under NDA so I can't put it online.